# Loops and Graphics in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to create a loop in Mathematica such that it creats multiple graphs for me. For example, I have a command of the form:

```
Plot3D[new[α, χ, τ] - old[τ], {α, 0, 2 π}, {χ, 0, π}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic] $$.
```

I can make a 3D graph for, say, `τ = 0.1`. What if I want to make multiple graphs for multiple values of `τ` -- say, for `τ = 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9 and 1.0`. That is, for 10 different vales of `τ`.

How would one going about this problem?

**Edit:** I couldn't find an appropriate tag for 'loops.'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)

```
old[τ_] := Sin[τ]
new[α_, χ_, τ_] := Sin[α τ]^2 + Cos[χ τ]^2

result = Table[Plot3D[ new[α, χ, τ] - old[τ], {α, 0, 2 π}, {χ, 0, π}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 0, AxesLabel -> Automatic] , {τ, 1/10, 1, 1/10}]
Export["result.gif", result]
```

[image]

[image]

Or use [`Animate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animate.html)

```
Animate[Plot3D[ new[α, χ, τ] - old[τ], {α, 0, 2 π}, {χ, 0, π}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 0, AxesLabel -> Automatic] , {τ, 1/10, 1, 1/10}]
```

For one graph use:

```
f = Table[new[α, χ, τ] - old[τ], {τ, 1/10, 1, 1/10}]
cd = Table[ColorData[97, c], {c, 10}]

Plot3D[Evaluate@f, {α, 0, 2 π}, {χ, 0, π}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 0, AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> cd]
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, I want them on separate graphs -- and not one.

Comment: @JunaidAftab Updated

Comment: This seems a flag in the wind